# How to reconstruct the expression parsed by jsep

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression, logical-operators

I've been scraping the web for how to construct the expression back from the parsed data from jsep.
Consider the expression

`(designation=="MANAGER" || function=="SALES") && cohortid=="1"`

This is the outpout from JSEP parser

```
{ type: 'LogicalExpression',
operator: '&&',
left: 
{ type: 'LogicalExpression',
 operator: '||',
 left: 
  { type: 'BinaryExpression',
    operator: '==',
    left: [Object],
    right: [Object] },
 right: 
  { type: 'BinaryExpression',
    operator: '==',
    left: [Object],
    right: [Object] } },
right: 
  { type: 'BinaryExpression',
 operator: '==',
 left: { type: 'Identifier', name: 'cohortid' },
 right: { type: 'Literal', value: '1', raw: '"1"' } } }
```

Now I want some library that can convert this/similar
output back to the initial expression.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/soney/jsep/issues/73) seems to be the closest the market has to offer...

Comment: If that library uses the [estree format](https://github.com/estree/estree), surely you will find some code that writes it back to a script - every transpiler does just this!

Comment: How do you get the output? Can you show your code snippet?